# Why do I have a validation error?

Tags: jquery, validation

My page in http://validator.w3.org show me an error in line:

```
$("<input type='text' />")
```

Why?
Isn't my code valid?
I present a piece of code. Please help.

```
<form action="{$smarty.const.APP_URL}user/login/" method="post">
    <table style="margin:0 auto 0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="25" name="user_login" value="Tw&#243;j login" onfocus="javascript:if(this.value=='Tw&#243;j login')this.value='';" onblur="javascript:if(this.value=='')this.value='Tw&#243;j login';" /></td>
            <td><input type="password" size="25" name="user_password" id="password" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="btnLogin" value="" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <p align="right"><a href="{$smarty.const.APP_URL}user/register/">utwórz konto</a> | <a href="{$smarty.const.APP_URL}user/password-reminder/">zapomniałem hasła</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
{/if}
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ("<input type='text' />")
            .attr("name", "password_mask")
            .attr("id", "password_mask")
            .attr("size","25")
            .val("Twoje has\u0142o")
            .insertAfter("#password");

        $("#password_mask").focus(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $("#password").show().focus();
        });

        $("#password").hide().blur(function() {
            if($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).hide();
                $("#password_mask").show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
{/literal}
</div>
```

Comment: `$` is missing in `("<input type='text' />")`

Comment: Also, are you passing PHP/Smarty code to the validator by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the DOCTYPE you have, the JavaScript code might need to be wrapped like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("<input type='text' />")
        //...
    });
//-->
</script>
```

This will effectively tell the HTML validator to ignore the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `$` missing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ("<input type='text' />")
---^
```

Replace it with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("<input type='text' />")
```

May be, the `{/if}`, `{literal}` smarty PHP tags might not get parsed by JavaScript, if they come without getting parsed by Smarty!

Comment: it should be a comment, you are not answering the question

Comment: @Pawel_W Actually I answered the question. Please check. I just asked a question in the end.

Comment: this is smarty template (notice other similar tags) so I don't know why you are asking about that {/if}

Comment: @Pawel_W Updated it. :) Please check. I know it is Smarty template.

Answer (score 0):

it's not about missing `$`, it is that validator doesn't parse JS - when it sees "" it treats it like a html node - try to move your javascript to external file